# Django queryset - get created object from database and equal the values

Tags: django, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, django-queryset

I wrote a simple selenium test that fills all fields from submit form (adding news on site). There is one of them below (title field):

```
# type title
    for t in range(2):
        try:
            title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='id_title']")
            print "I found text!"
            title.send_keys("SomeText")
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print "I didn't find it!"
    else:
        print "Retry"
```

It success and in /admin/news/ (Django) I am able to see my automatically filled new article.

Right now I'd like to check if the data send from this form equals to the data the is being stored on database.

Does anyone would explain how to use a proper queryset to retrieve these data and print the results ? I've created a new class and by a logic I think it's gonna be something like below:

```
class NewsModelTestCompare(TestCase):
    def test_creating_news(self):
    # getting object
    n = News.objects.get(title="SomeText")

    self.assertEqual(News.objects.get(pk=n.id), n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the data is already in database, you could first query on `News` model with the data submitted from the form and check if database returns any result, like:

```
matching_objects = News.objects.filter(title="SomeText")
# this means the query returned at least one result
self.assertNotEqual(matching_objects.count(), 0)
```